# Show that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic for any $n > 3.$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I need some help with the following question.

> Show that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic for any $n > 3.$

There is the following  hint in my book: *find two distinct subgroups of order $2.$*

But I don't see any subgroups of order $2.$   Is group $(\mathbb{Z}/2  \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$  subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}?$ Show the second  subgroup, please.

Comment: Remember the superscript $\times$ means the multiplicative group of invertible elements in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$.  Here $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is not of order $2$ (nor is it quite clear how you make that a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ for $n \gt 1$, except in the sense that it corresponds to the trivial subgroup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(2^n-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$, $\langle 2^{n}-1 \rangle$ is a subgroup of order 2. Also, since $n \geq 3$, $(1+2^{n-1})^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$, so $\langle 1+2^{n-1} \rangle$ has order 2. It should be easy to see that these subgroups are distinct, as $n \neq 1$.